# XSL: Greater than AND lower than?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to create various options that depend on the value of a variable I've set. The following code works as intended:

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$weight &lt; 30">
        <carrier_grid_1>DHL</carrier_grid_1>
            <shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>1</shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$weight &gt; 60">
        <carrier_grid_3>Pallet Network</carrier_grid_3>
            <shipping_time_carrier_grid_3>1</shipping_time_carrier_grid_3>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

When I try to do something like this however, it fails and doesn't run:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$weight &gt; 30 and &lt; 60">
        <carrier_grid_2>DX or TNT</carrier_grid_2>
        <shipping_time_carrier_grid_2>1</shipping_time_carrier_grid_2>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

I've tried looking online but was unable to find anything to help. Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget the case where $weight equals 30 (or 60) exactly!

Comment: 'Fails and doesn't run' is not a problem description. Try again. What happens instead? NB This is not Cobol: there are no abbreviated combined conditions in XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following change

```
<xsl:when test="$weight &gt; 30 and $weight &lt; 60">
```

Comment: In XPath 2.0 assuming `$weight` is an integer, you can also write `$weight = (31 to 59)`, but it relies on good optimisation so it might be a bit too "clever".

Comment: @yes Michael Kay but i am not change user code only modify. I take care next time